# gluing manifolds along boundaries

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a problem with the following task.

Suppose $M_1, M_2$ are smooth manifolds with boundary. Let $f_1, f_2$ be diffeomorphisms from $B_1$ to $B_2$ ($B_i$ - the boundary of $M_i$), and suppose $f_1, f_2$ are isotopic. Show, that $M_1\cup_{f_1} M_2$ and $M_1\cup_{f_2}M_2$ are diffeomorphic.

Comment: Do you mean that $B_i$ is the boundary of $M_i$?

Comment: Yes, $B_i$ is the boundary of $M_i$.

Comment: Then you should edit your post and erase the word "component".

Comment: WLG $B_i$ is the boundary of $M_i$, but it also could be a component of the boundary. It doesn`t matter.

Comment: Use the isotopy extension theorem.

Comment: Is there a elementary solution? I do not know this theorem and it seems a little bit complicated for me.